# How to handle onclick events from multiple dynamically created anchor tags using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, onclick

I have multiple dynamically created anchor tags that work as buttons. When any of these buttons are clicked, I want to call a single javascript function that sits in another file, which will do the rest of the fun work. My problem is that I cannot properly call the function via the 'onclick' event, so I am trying to find a way around it but it's just not so simple for me.

I have tried many different ways so I understand a few limitations with this approach:

Standard HTML anchor with Javascript:

```
<a href=#" onclick="doSomething(parameter1, parameter2, ...);">Button</a>
```

This is not going to help because there are synchronization issues and I have found that href will be chosen above on click almost always I have found. I actually would love this way to work, if you know any workarounds here then please let me know.

Binding via JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#button_id").click(function() {
         doSomething(parameter1, parameter2, ...);
     });
});
```

My issue with binding is that when the page is loaded, I have a function that gets the data from the database and displays it in a list. Each list element has a button, which 'on click' will call a javascript function, passing it parameters according to whatever data I need to give it from the list element, and it then will do something.

I understand that in order for Binding to work well, each button should have its own ID so that its easy to associate them with the Binding method. However, I am not sure how to tell the the .click function how many ID's I have, nor how to give it these parameters (unless I capture them via button ID by calling other JS functions).

Any suggestions/ideas are highly appreciated!

EDIT:
How do I go about adding the button_data to the parameters of the 'doSomething(parameter);' function?

```
list_element = '<span class="ui-li-count" data-mini="true">' + button_data + '<a href="#" class="my_button">Button</a>';</span>
```

Please remember this data is obtained dynamically from the database and posted onto the site when the page is first loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use an `id` for this. That's the opposite of what you need to be doing  since you are giving a group of element identical functionality. Instead, you should be giving them a `class` to group them:

```
<a href=#" class="my-button">Button</a>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('body').on('click', '.my-button', function() {
         doSomething(parameter1, parameter2, ...);
     });
});
```

This will bind the click event to all `.my-button` elements, even ones that you haven't created yet. Replace `body` with the parent element that contains all of the buttons to make this work a bit faster.

Comment: what about the data that will be passed into the parameters? assume this: my_list = '<a href=#" class="my-button">'+button_data+'</a>' How would I go about giving 'button_data' to the doSomething function? I will write this in my post (read above)

Comment: Store it in a `data-` attribute and access it via jQuery's `.data()` function.

Comment: Can you suggest somewhere I can obtain examples of the usage of .data() I've been reading about it for a few hours but it isn't working for me yet :/

Comment: If your element has a data attribute named `data-foo`, you call `.data('foo')` on its jQuery object to return the value: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 1):

Use the .on() function.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

You could also add a specific prefix to the id like `test_<id>` and then you can use wild card selectors:

```
$("[id^=test]").on('click', function () {
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion on the .on() function, this approach is just great. However, Blender above is right I should be using 'class' instead of 'id'.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if like me, you prefer raw JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<script type="text/JavaScript">

function createAnchor( strParentElementId, strLinkText, strLinkHref, intArg1, intArg2 ) {

    var objAnchor   = null;
    var objParent   = document.getElementById( strParentElementId );
    var boolCreated = false;

    if ( objParent != null ) {

        objAnchor = document.createElement( 'A' );
        if ( objAnchor != null ) {

            with ( objAnchor ) {
                style.color = 'yellow';
                innerText   = strLinkText;
                href        = strLinkHref;
                onclick     = function() { doSomething( intArg1, intArg2 ); }
                } //with

            objParent.appendChild( objAnchor );

            boolCreated = true;
            } //if-create-element
       }  //if-get-parent

return boolCreated;
}

function doSomething( intArg1, intArg2 ) {
    alert( 'doSomething( ' + intArg1.toString() + ', ' + intArg2.toString() + ' );' );
return true;
}

</script>

<body>

<a name="hello">Hello</a><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<a name="world">World!</a><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />


<div id="myDiv1" style="background-color:red;"></div><br />
<div id="myDiv2" style="background-color:red;"></div><br />


<script type="text/JavaScript">
createAnchor( 'myDiv1', 'Link 1 - Hello', '#hello', 1, 2 );
createAnchor( 'myDiv2', 'Link 2 - World', '#world', 3, 4 );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```